# Design pattern for caching dynamic user content (in django)

Tags: django, design-patterns, database-design, optimization, memcached

On my website I'm going to provide points for some activities, similarly to stackoverflow. I would like to calculate value basing on many factors so each computation for each user will take for instance 10 SQL queries.

I was thinking about caching it:

- in memcache,
- in user's row in database (so that wherever I need to get user from base I easly show the points)

Storing in database seems easy but on other hand it's redundant information and I decided to ask, since maybe there is easier and prettier solution which I missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd highly recommend this app for storing the calculated values in the model: https://github.com/initcrash/django-denorm

Memcache is faster than the db... but if you already have to retrieve the record from the db anyway, having the calculated values cached in the rows you're retrieving (as a 'denormalised' field) is even faster, plus it's persistent.